# PHP How to process a form that has dynamically generated fields?

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to process a form which I don't know ahead of time what the form fields will be.  Can this still be done in PHP?

For example I have this html form:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
     <?php get_dynamic_fields(); // this gets all the fields from DB which I don't know ahead of time what they are. ?>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
</form>
```

And here is what I have in the PHP process file

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && $_POST['submit'] === 'submit' ) {
     // process form here but how do I know what field names and such if they are dynamic.
}

?>
```

Here is a caveat: assuming I can't get the data from the db ahead of time, is there still a way to do this?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` will show you what you're receiving. You should have **SOME** way of processing the data, otherwise what's the point of building the form in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just [iterate](http://php.net/foreach) over all the items in the [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.post.php) array:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // Do something with $key and $value
}
```

Note, your submit button will exist in the array `$_POST`, so you may want to write some code to handle that.

Comment: So I take it doing it this way I can only sanitize the inputs but can't really know if a certain field is required.  So I can't really do validation is that correct?

Comment: @Rick:  That's dependant on if you're able to get field names and other information from another one of your form building functions.

Comment: Ok then it sounds like I have to pull the data out of the db first to check against the submitted inputs...I was trying to avoid that...thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all $_POST keys like this.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key.": ".$value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the field names used in HTML form.

```
$field_names = array_keys($_POST);
```

You can also just iterate through the POST array using

```
foreach($_POST as $field_name => $field_value) {
    // do what ever you need to do
    /* with the field name  and field value */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the names of the fields from your `get_dynamic_fields` function and pass them in a hidden input that is always an array with a static name. Then parse it to get the names of the inputs and how many there are.

Answer (score 0):

you could loop over all parts of the `$_POST array;

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
   //$key contains the name of the field
}
```